# Using when with whereHas in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have the following query:

```
return Expense::with('descriptions')
    ->when($this->string, function ($query) {
        return $query->where('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $this->string . '%');
    })
    ->orWhereHas('tags', function ($query) {
        $query->where('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $this->string . '%');
    })
    ->get();
```

What I need is, to use the `whereHas` with the `when`, somehow. If `$this->string` is empty, the `whereHas` shouldn't be used. Since it will return everything that has a `Tag` like this, and I only need to run that when `$this->string` is not empty.

Any way to write this cleanly? I do not want to use if/else to check wether `$this->string` is set and then return something different.

Comment: Can't you just move `orWhereHas()` into the `when()` closure?

Comment: Seems like an if statement or conditional of some sort would make sense here. Why don't you want to do that? Have you tried nesting the orWhereHas within the when statement? You just need to be careful in that case to keep your $query variables in order.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your **whereHas** depends on an external variable, the best approach is construct your query with conditional statements evaluating your variables.

Don't be afraid to split the construction of your query in multiple steps, you don't need chain everything and return it.

It's more readable something like this:

```
$builder = Expense::with('descriptions')
                ->where('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $this->string . '%');

if ($this->string) {
    $builder = $builder->whereHas('tags', function ($query) {
        $query->where('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $this->string . '%');
    });
}
return $builder->get();
```

Comment: Accepted this answer since indeed it does look more clean. Had to change to `$builder = $builder->orWhereHas` for my case though.

Answer (score 2):

You want something like this?

```
return Expense::with('descriptions')
    ->when(!empty($this->string), function ($query) {
        return $query->WhereHas('tags', function ($query) {
            $query->where('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $this->string . '%');
        })
    })
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    return Person::with('employeeProfile')
        ->WhereHas('employeeProfile', function ($query) use ($request) {
         $query->when($request->department_id, function ($query) use ($request) {
         return   $query->where('department_id', '=', $request->department_id);
                 });
               })
        ->get();
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).